# Getting current song info from online radio/tv

Tags: php, internet-radio

I'd like to get the song or program name details from a particular online radio/tv broadcast url. This url could be a file with *.pls extension or in form of mms protocol.

Is there any web request technic, library for php or any popular language?

Comment: there is a pls file link like http://eksensc.radyotvonline.com/listen.pls

Comment: i don't understand why did this question get such negative points? is this a really terrible question?

Comment: Consider this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44050266/get-info-from-streaming-radio

Comment: The negative response to the question is because it does not show research effort, and questions asking for libraries are usually off topic.

Answer (score 0):

i am not so sure that this answer will help you, but it can lead you to solution

```
$url    = parse_url(URL);
```

abouve url will give you an array of the following format

```
Array
```

`(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => eksensc.radyotvonline.com
    [path] => /listen.pls
)`

you can get `$url['path']` from that array,

Hope it hepls ! Thanks